# Stack in hardware or cache

Tags: stack, microprocessors

Why isnt it more widespread to implement the function call stack in hardware or at least have it closer to the CPU in the L1/L2 cache ?

Couldn't it save stacking/reading back function parameters to registers in the CPU by not having to travel to the memory each time ?

Comment: What do you mean with "implement in hardware"? Also, the cache does exactly that, avoiding to travel to memory each time, for commonly used values.

Comment: Well I read that some microprocessors have dedicated hardware for the stack : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)#Hardware_stacks Scroll to "Stack in registers or dedicated memory". That does limit the size of the stack though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, its a matter of price/performance trade of. For many reasons Modern CPU's use SRAM chips as cache. Unfortunately, SRAM is 1000 times pricier then cheap DDR3 you can buy at your local PC store. So, since you probably won't buy 15,000$ i7 CPU, just because it has 1 gig of SRAM L1 cache, no one will produce such. [price/performance](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/mckinley/352/lectures/21.pdf)

Actually, CPU's implements sophisticate methods to compensate the lack of memory. Look for "cache management".